# Granting access to a file or directory to another user but not all users in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

How to allow one user -- but not all -- to access files of another user in Ubuntu?

I have a directory `/home/alice/dir` owned by `alice`:

```
$ cd /home/alice
$ ls -l
drwxr-x---  2 alice alice       4096 Feb 10 21:24 dir
```

i.e., owner `alice` and group `alice` have read/execute access. Of course, `/home` and `/home/alice` are readable/executable for all (`drwxr-xr-x`), which is the default configuration for Ubuntu.

I want to allow user `bob` access to this directory, but any other user `eve` should not have access.

What I did so far was:

```
$ sudo adduser bob alice
```

and now

```
$ getent group alice
alice:x:1001:bob
```

so now `bob` is in the group `alice`.

However, still `bob` cannot access the directory:

```
$ whoami
bob
$ cd /home/alice
$ pwd
/home/alice
$ ls -l
drwxr-x---  2 alice alice       4096 Feb 10 21:24 dir
$ groups bob
bob : bob alice
$ cd dir
bash: cd: test: Permission denied
```

What's wrong?

Users were created with

```
sudo adduser alice
sudo adduser bob
sudo adduser eve
```

Ubuntu 14.04. I think ACL are not used, and I don't want to use them -- I think what I want should be perfectly achievable without ACL.

Answer (score 4):

The way of doing it as described in the question is correct:

```
$ sudo adduser bob alice
```

However, you will not see the changes immediately: all currently running processes and services must be restarted for them to see the changes.

This is because when you update the groups, the permissions of the currently running processes and services, including your shell, are not updated. So in my case `groups` (current shell started by `bob` before the groups were changed) and `groups bob` (current permissions of user `bob`) showed different results:

```
$ whoami
bob
$ groups bob # current membership of bob
bob alice
$ groups     # shell run by bob BEFORE the groups changed
bob
$ cd /home/alice/dir
bash: cd: test: Permission denied
```

So I had to close the shell, and even close the tunnel (I was connected to the Ubuntu box via an SSH tunnel) and open a new shell (after I connected to SSH again) and then I saw

```
$ whoami
bob
$ groups bob
bob alice
$ groups     # current shell run by bob AFTER the groups changed
bob alice
$ cd /home/alice/dir
$ pwd
/home/alice/dir
```

If `bob` is a service, such as `apache2` (running under user `www-data`), that service is to be restarted!

Comment: As your answer is great, I'd like to suggest adding that all the above directories (/home/alice) should be group readable and(?) executable too, otherwise /home/alice/dir still can't be reached.

Comment: Thank you! I added this at the top of the question (not answer).